# how to display a boolean values in twig

Tags: symfony, boolean, field

in this table i want to display in the "reponse" field "yes" or "no" instead of "1" and " "
this is the picture show my table :
[this picture shows my table :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA36D.png)

i'm using symfony2.8,in my entity "typeQuestion" i have this :

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(name="reponse", type="boolean")
 */

private $reponse;


/**
 * Set reponse
 *
 * @param boolean $reponse
 * @return TypeQuestion
 */
public function setReponse($reponse)
{
    $this->reponse = $reponse;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get reponse
 *
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function getReponse()
{
    return $this->reponse;
}
 public function __toString() {
    return $this->libelle;
}
```

}

in the form i have:

```
 ->add('reponse', 'choice', array(
                'label' => 'Reponse',
                'choices' => array("true" => 'Oui', false => 'Non'),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true
            ));
}
```

and i have this in my view:

```
 <td class="center">{{TypeQuestion.libelle}}</td>
<td class="center">{{TypeQuestion.description}}</td> 
<td class="center">{{TypeQuestion.reponse}}</td>
```

in phpmyadmin this is what i get :
in phpmyadmin this is what i get :[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6auih.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add if statement `{% if TypeQuestion.reponse %}yes{% else %}no{% endif%}`

Answer (score 56):

This is what I normally do:

```
{{ someBoolean ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}
```

Reference: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators

Answer (score 2):

Even though the answer accepted is valid, I don't think it is quite versatile. Imagine you print this in hundreds of template and you want to change the label over time.

You will have to update all your templates, and if your applications goes multilingual…

The best practice is to translate your text.

Ex :

```
{% if TypeQuestion.reponse %}
  {{ 'answer.true' | trans({}, 'your_trans_catalog') }}
{% else %}
  {{ 'answer.false' | trans({}, 'your_trans_catalog') }}
{% endif%}
```

This ways you can easily handle, new possibilities, and new languages without changing your templates.