# How to pass twig variable/function as parameter in html?

Tags: vue.js, twig, vue-component

`isMyAnalyticsActive` is being read from .env.local in symfony project. Dump values are always correct but I simply cant assign the boolean value to vuecomponent parameter `is-my-analytics-active`

{% set isMyAnalyticsActive = activateMyAnalytics() %}

```
{% block body %}

{{ dump(activateMyAnalytics()) }}
{{ dump(isMyAnalyticsActive) }}
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-5">
          <company-support 
          :items="{{ items|json_encode }}"
          :is-my-analytics-active="{{ isMyAnalyticsActive }}"/> // Problem here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CompanySupport is my vue componnet and here is `isMyAnalyticsActive` defined as follows:

```
props: {
  items: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => [],
  },
  isMyAnalyticsActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
```

if value is true I get following error:

[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "isMyAnalyticsActive". Expected Boolean, got Number with value 1.

if value is false I get following error:

The value for a v-bind expression cannot be empty. Found in "v-bind:is-my-analytics-active"
and everything crashes after dumps.

Comment: The error means what it says, you provided "1" value where JS boolean was expected. It's not shown how it looks on the side of symphony but proceed from the fact that you need `{{ isMyAnalyticsActive }}` to be interpolated to `true` or `false`, or change prop type to suit raw value  better

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973606/how-to-display-a-boolean-values-in-twig

Comment: I tried `{{ someBoolean ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}` but it didnt work.

Comment: You need it to be something like {{ isMyAnalyticsActive ? 'true' : 'false' }} , not just pasted

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you very much this worked I actually used `{{ isMyAnalyticsActive ? true : false }}` without the quotes... coming from java world :(